# GridView doesn't update in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

When I load my View for the first time I do the following code to set GridView Source:

```
ObservableCollection<Categories> categories = await TargetUtils.GetCategoriesRemoteAsync(year);

collectionTarget.Source = categories;
```

Everything is ok until I try update my gridview with adding some new Items, as so many tutorials found on internet I've used ObservableCollection and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to update it.

My INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

My category class:

```
public class Categories : Model
{

    public String Type { get; set; }
    public List<MetaDados> MetaDados { get; set; }

    public Categories(String Type)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
    }
}

public class MetaDados : Model
{
 //NORMAL IMPLEMENTATION
}
```

and to update I do:

```
await TargetUtils.GetParcellableCategoriesRemoteAsync(Constants.FULL, year, (ObservableCollection<Categories>)collectionTarget.Source);
```

that calls:

```
    public static async Task<ObservableCollection<Categories>> GetParcellableCategoriesRemoteAsync(String type, int year, ObservableCollection<Categories> categories)
    {

        foreach (Categories c in categories)
        {
            if (c.Type.Equals(type))
            {
                c.MetaDados = await LoadMetaDadosTask.loadMetaDados(type, year, c.MetaDados);
            }
        }

        return categories;
    }
```

finally:

```
public static async Task<List<MetaDados>> loadMetaDados(String type, int year, List<MetaDados> metaDados)
        {

         //MY UPDATE CODE AND:

         metaDados.Add(PARAMETERS);

         return metaDados;
        }
```

I have no idea why my gridView doesn't update if I'm using ObservableCollection and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, some help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sanket already mentioned, you need to call `OnPropertyChanged` when property value changes. The best place to do it is inside the property setter, e.g.

```
private String _type;
public String Type 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _type;
    }
    set
    {
        _type = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Type");
    }
}
```

This way, every time you set a new value to the property, `PropertyChanged` event will be raised.

Apart from that, I think it would be a better idea to use `ObservableList<MetaDados>` instead of `List<MetaDados>` for `Categories.MetaDados` property because you are onyl adding new items to the existing list and `INotifyCollectionChanged` implemented by `ObservableCollection<T>` could notify the `GridView` about it. The change will also be rendered more fluently since only the item items in the collection will change instead of the whole collection.

Additionally, otherwise it could even happen that the `GridView` will ignore the `PropertyChanged` on `Categories.MetaDados` because the same instance of the list has been assigned that is already rendered.

Comment: It's still not working, :( I don't know what to do, I already did everything

Comment: @VictorOliveira Including using `ObservableCollection<T>` for `Categories.MetaDados`?

Answer (score 0):

Only implementing INotifyPropertyChanged will not help you.

You will need to Raise ProeprtyChagned event as well. Otherwise, binding will not know that there is a change.

Call Raise Property Change event once you are done loading Categories onto ObservableCollection and You are good to go.